# What does 'that she thought away' mean in this poem?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I can't understand the italicized part of the following poem, My Mother at Sixty-six by Kamala Das:

> Driving from my parent’s
>   home to Cochin last Friday
>   morning, I saw my mother,
>   beside me,
>   doze, open mouthed, her face
>   ashen like that
>   of a corpse and realised with
>   pain
>   *that she thought away*, and
>   looked but soon
>   put that thought away, and
>   looked out at young
>   trees sprinting, the merry children spilling
>   out of their homes,

Comment: You're not supposed to understand it. [It's a typo](http://books.google.com/books?id=4kqjuarqYiIC&q=%22pain+that+she+was+as+old+as+she+looked%22&dq=%22pain+that+she+was+as+old+as+she+looked%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=7tBWVOPnDqPdsATqw4DgDw&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAA). One line has been left out and another has been duplicated.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo

Answer (score 2):

As Peter Shor notes, the highlighted words are part of a garbled line. According to [Answers.com](http://www.answers.com/Q/What_is_the_poem_mother_at_sixty_six_by_kamala_das), the correct words after "realised with pain" are not "that she thought away, and looked" but "that she was as old as she looked."

The error seems to have gained considerable reach by having occurred in [a book](http://books.google.com/books?id=W-PbF9dEnfsC&pg=RA4-PA1&lpg=RA4-PA1&dq=%22home+to+Cochin+last+Friday+morning%22&source=bl&ots=9WSV5KHp_u&sig=WtMmbghkJPulm0ExkigpE5o6AEc&hl=en&sa=X&ei=bzNXVMJc2OugBOufgOgN&ved=0CCQQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22home%20to%20Cochin%20last%20Friday%20morning%22&f=false) that offers "chapterwise syllabus coverage in question and answer form" of different aspects of English reading and writing as preparation for various standardized tests. (See Practice Question number 2 in chapter 7 for the mangled lines of poetry.)